# Form using a js and array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

The company I am working for is transferring their website from an old design to a new design. There was a form set up on the old website which I'm transferring to the new website and I cannot seem to get it to work. It works fine on the old website. The purpose of the form is to type in a zip code and then submit, then it will link to a specific page depending on the zip code entered. Here is the form code I'm using in the HTML:

```
<input id="zip" type="text" name="zip" maxlength="5" />
<input id="zipButton" onclick="validateZip()" type="button"
name="zipButton" value="Submit" />
```

Here is the JS I'm using/linking to:

```
function isValidUSZip(zip) {
return /^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/.test(zip);
};

function programURL(zip){
    var i;
    for (i=0; i <XZIP.length; i++){
    if (XZIP[i] == zip){
        document.location = XWebPages[i];
        return;
    }
    else if (XZIP[i] != zip){
        document.location = 'error.html';
    }
}
};
function validateZip() {
var zip = $('#zip').val();
if(isValidUSZip(zip) == true) {
    programURL(zip);
}
else {
    document.location = 'error.html';
}
};
```

Here is the the array I'm using/linking to:

```
var lsz = 4;

var XWebPages = Array([lsz]);
var XZIP = Array([lsz]);

XWebPages[0] = "http://www.url.com";
XZIP[0] = "91350";

XWebPages[1] = "http://www.url.com";
XZIP[1] = "93551";

XWebPages[2] = "http://www.url.com";
XZIP[2] = "93544";

XWebPages[3] = "http://www.url.com";
XZIP[3] = "93536";
```

Am I missing some part of it? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post "test" function? Without it, javascript will give you an error such as "test is not defined".

Comment: @Vini.g.fer test is a method of the regex object.

Comment: Check your loop! You redirect to the error page after the first unmatched value instead of looping through the rest of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If the zip code isn't found in the array in the first time through the loop, then the document.location = 'error.html' will be reached before the search completes.  Please consider taking this out of the loop, and maybe setting the error page as a default, storing the URL in a string and breaking the loop if a match is found.  Then do the redirect, if that's what you want to do; maybe like this:

```
function programURL(zip){
  var i;
  var newlocation = 'error.html'; // set default page
  var found = 0;

  for (i=0; i <XZIP.length && found == 0; i++) {
    if (XZIP[i] == zip){
        newlocation = XWebPages[i];
        found = 1;
    }
  }
  document.location = newlocation;
};
```